# Applying white noise to PID model in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, transfer, noise

I'd like to exclusively apply a white noise signal to a PID model in matlab.  I know how to both generate this signal and how to add white noise to the other signals, but I have no idea how to apply only the white noise.

I tried to use `lsim` function but this one needs signals in time domain and in my white noise signal I have only values and samples. Below is how I created white noise (`X`):

```
L=100000; %Sample length for the random signal
mu=0;
sigma=2;
X=sigma*randn(L,1)+mu;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on where you want to add the noise:

- Noise on the input

  ```
  lsim(sys, u+X, t);
  ```
- Noise on the output

  ```
  Y = lsim(sys, u, t) + X;
  ```
- Additive process noise: in this case you need to use [`sim`](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/sim.html), which is an [extension of `lsim`](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/sim.html#btejzbm-11)

  Useful links:

  - [Overview of the simulated model](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/sim.html#bux1ldp-5)
  - [Example](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/sim.html#bux1q16-1)